# Is it possible with compass to loop through a folder and generate css classes of the files within?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Say I'm having a folder `images/icons` that contains:

```
apple.png
banana.png
kiwi.png
```

Is it possible with compass/sass to loop through the folder and create css definitions like

```
.fruit-apple {
    background-image: url(images/icons/apple.png);
}
```

I'm aware of [compass' sprite functionality](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) that can be used like

```
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

But can this be used without having compass create sprite images somehow? I just want to loop through a folder and create some style definitions based on the available files.

Comment: Explain why you don't want sprites? Sprites reduce the amount of web traffic to your server. Unless you have a vertical repeating image I don't see why you can't use sprites.

Comment: You just gave the answer on your own. I need to use the images as repeating background images.

Comment: Just found the answer in a similar question - it needs to be solved with a custom function written in ruby.